# Cmake cannot find module Qt5WebEngineWidgets

Tags: arch-linux, cmake

I want to compile QSyncthingTray (https://github.com/sieren/QSyncthingTray) on my notebook running arch linux x86.

I've set $QTDIR to

```
/home/user/.qt/5.5/gcc/
```

as well as $CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

I've even set $Qt5WebEngineWidgets_DIR to

```
/home/user/.qt/5.5/gcc/lib/cmake/Qt5WebEngineWidgets
```

The directory exists and the required files are in there.

Cmake still errors

```
CMake Warning at /usr/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake:326 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"Qt5WebEngineWidgets" with any of the following names:

Qt5WebEngineWidgetsConfig.cmake
qt5webenginewidgets-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Qt5WebEngineWidgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5WebEngineWidgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5WebEngineWidgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:127 (qt5_use_modules)


CMake Error at /usr/lib/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreMacros.cmake:328 (message):
Can not use "WebEngineWidgets" module which has not yet been found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:127 (qt5_use_modules)
```

Answer (score 1):

---

> »» Can not use "WebEngineWidgets" module which has not yet been found ««

`Qt5WebEngineWidgets` seems to be provided by **qtwebengine**-opensource-src-5.6.0.tar.xz https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.0/submodules/

? Easier to build version 5.4 ? : qtwebengine-5.4.1 →  qtwebengine-opensource-src-5.4.1.tar.xz ... The patch qtwebengine-opensource-src-5.4.0-gyp_conf.patch (and the .tar.xz) can be found in `qt5-qtwebengine-5.4.1-1.fc21.src.rpm`  ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/devel%3A/cloverleaf%3A/testing%3A/frameworks/devel_cloverleaf_testing_Fedora_21/src/qt5-qtwebengine-5.4.1-1.fc21.src.rpm

---

EDIT : QSyncthingTray can be built with qtwebengine-5.6 only. Fails with v5.4 .

I found an OS with a working qtwebengine-5.6 : PCLinuxOS 2016 - 64bits → `lib64qt5webengine-devel-5.6.0-2pclos2016`, and QSyncthingTray builds in a few seconds.

---

Comment: @Unkn0wn : Please see my edited post. -